# Find closure of sets w.r.t product topology?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

Consider the cartesian product $$X= ⨉_{r \in[0,1]} \ [0,\infty) = \{\text{all functions } f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,\infty)\}$$

with the (product) topology generated by the projections
$$
S = \{p_r^{-1}(U) \colon r \in [0,1], U \subseteq [0,\infty) \text{ open}\}.
$$

Let $A \subseteq X$. How can I in general compute the closure of $A$ with respect to this topology?

Say for instance $A=\{f \in X \colon f >0\}$? Can anyone help me in the right direction?

I would like to get a better grasp on the product topologies!

---

**Update:**

I now think I have cracked how to do it for sets like $A$: We can use the fact that in the product topology
$$
\overline{⨉_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha} = ⨉_{\alpha \in I} \overline{U_\alpha}. 
$$
So we obtain that
$$
\overline{A} = \overline{\{f \in X \colon f >0\}} = \overline{⨉_{r \in(0,1]} \ (0,\infty)} = ⨉_{r \in(0,1]} \ \overline{(0,\infty)} = ⨉_{r \in(0,1]} \ [0,\infty) = X.
$$

I am wondering if this is the default method or there is something better? Say we for instance instead want to find the closure of as set like

$$
B=\{f \in X \colon \{ x \in [0,1] \colon f(x) >0 \} \text{ is finite } \}
$$

I can't really find any way to write this as a cartesian product since the condition of finite non-zero is a "local" property for each $f$. Is it possible or is there another way to tackle this? If we could write it as a cartesian product then we would be done by the above method.

Any thoughts or help is appreciated!

Comment: Convergence in the product space is point-wise convergence.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The closure of $\{f: f>0\}$ is $\{f: f\geq 0\}$.

Comment: The closure of $A$ is just $X$.

Comment: I have updated the question to include a set that (perhaps) is not as easy as the original. The method I have used does not immediately seem to work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you've used for $A$ seems to be computing the sequential closure, so I don't think an analogous method for $B$ exists, as the sequential closure of $B$ is strictly smaller than the closure of $B$. In such a case, I only know how to show it from the basis of the product topology as follows:

---

Since $S$ is a subbasis for the product topology, we have the basis elements
$$\bigcap_{r \in I}p_r^{-1}(U_r)$$
where $I\subset [0,1]$ is a finite index set and each $U_r \subseteq [0,\infty)$ is open.  In particular, these basis elements are nonempty if and only if each $U_r$ is nonempty.

Suppose now we have a nonempty basis element in the given form.  Then there is a function $f : [0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ so that $f(r) \in U_r$ and $f(x) = 0$ whenever $x \not\in I$.  Therefore $f \in \bigcap_{r \in I}p_r^{-1}(U_r)$.

Additionally, we see that $\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) > 0\} \subseteq I$ is finite, so $f \in B$.  Therefore $$B \cap \bigcap_{r \in I}p_r^{-1}(U_r) \neq \emptyset.$$

That is, $B$ is dense in $X$, so its closure is $X$.

---

As an additional problem that begs to be asked by the above: Show that the sequential closure of $B$ is sequentially closed but is not equal to $X$.  In particular, $X$ is not a [sequential space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

Comment: Which definition of dense are you using? My definition of dense is exactly that the closure is the entire set (point 3. on wikipedia) . Are you using 8.? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set#Definition

Comment: @Jacobiman Yes.  Specifically, I'm using the implication $(8) \implies (2)$ from wikipedia's list of equivalent conditions.

Comment: Yes, my mistake I meant point (2), not (3). The question is if the easiest thing is to show that $(8) \implies (2)$ and then use your proof or if one can show the above in a more direct manner. Maybe someone can help clarify this? For now, I shall attempt to first, thanks for your help Brian  :)

Comment: +1. An additional useful instruction is that a member of the base (basis) generated by the "canonical" sub-base is of the form $\prod_{x\in [0,1]}V_x$ where each $V_x$ is open in $[0,\infty)$ and $\{x\in [0,1]:V_x\ne [0,\infty)\}$ is finite.